# Javascript get element by ID and his inside value

Tags: javascript, string, getelementbyid

This is what i have inside javascript

```
function xmlhttpPost(strURL,formname,responsediv,responsemsg) {

    var xmlHttpReq = false;

    var self = this;

    // Xhr per Mozilla/Safari/Ie7

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    }

    // per tutte le altre versioni di IE

    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);

    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {

            // Quando pronta, visualizzo la risposta del form

            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText,responsediv);

        }

        else{

            // In attesa della risposta del form visualizzo il msg di attesa

            updatepage(responsemsg,responsediv);



        }

    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring(formname));

}



function getquerystring(formname) {

    var qstr = document.getElementById[formname];

    return qstr;

}

function updatepage(str,responsediv){

    document.getElementById(responsediv).innerHTML = str;

}
```

First it was deveoped for FORM value, and easy i can transfer POST VALUES in another PHP file,and make a query, now i want to modified it just simple transfer some value of one element in new file, that is going to be loaded ajax in another element and do query, where i got wrong and how to echo value from this class in another file?

Comment: When you are passing `formname`, is it the `name` attribute of a `<form>`, or `id` attribute?

Comment: Is Formname, but i have modified form function to return just value od id and get id, now i dont know how to echo that value

Answer (score 2):

You should use `()` instead of `[]` to make an actual function call (in this case `getElementById`). Furthermore, if you want the content of the element, use the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) properties:

```
function getquerystring(what) {

    var qstr = document.getElementById(what);

    return qstr.innerHTML;

}
```

The `[]` are property accessors in object or arrays.

Comment: you beat me to it: already made an jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Diabl0570/NuFW5/1

Comment: `textContent || innerText` maybe? For oldIE

Answer (score 1):

To get the contents of the div, return the innerHTML property and change `[]` to `()`.

```
function getquerystring(what) {
    var qstr = document.getElementById(what).innerHTML;
    return qstr;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T8eTZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parentheses "()" for the function call. Also, you want `innerText` of the element, not the whole element.

```
function getquerystring(what) {
    var qstr = document.getElementById(what);
    return qstr.innerText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get text inside the div, try this:

```
<div id="test">
  Some <span class="foo">sample</span> text.
</div>

function getquerystring(what) {
var node = document.getElementById(what),

var htmlContent = node.innerHTML; // htmlContent would give "Some <span class='foo'>sample</span> text."
var textContent = node.textContent; // textContent would give "Some sample text."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the text in between your div by using the following code,
For reference [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3aelement.innerHTML), [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2bGc/)

```
function getquerystring(what) {

    var qstr = document.getElementById(what).innerHTML;

    return qstr;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
function getquerystring(what) {

    var qstr = document.getElementById[what].innerHTML;

    return qstr;

}
```